# How to change the swap file size permanently

Tags: 18.04, swap

A [previous thread](https://askubuntu.com/a/1075516/879604) explains how to resize the swap file in Ubuntu 18.  I used it successfully.  But on reboot, the swap file reverts to its previous size.  Is there a straightforward way to make that change permanent?

**`lsblk -f`**

`AME         FSTYPE  LABEL UUID                                   MOUNTPOINT
loop0        squashf                                              /snap/core/603
loop1        squashf                                              /snap/gnome-lo
loop2        squashf                                              /snap/core18/5
loop3        squashf                                              /snap/hextris/
loop4        squashf                                              /snap/core18/4
loop5        squashf                                              /snap/core18/5
loop6        squashf                                              /snap/gnome-ca
loop7        squashf                                              /snap/gnome-ca
loop8        squashf                                              /snap/gimp/88
loop9        squashf                                              /snap/gtk-comm
loop10       squashf                                              /snap/gnome-ch
loop11       squashf                                              /snap/gnome-3-
loop12       squashf                                              /snap/gnome-3-
loop13       squashf                                              /snap/skype/60
loop14       squashf                                              /snap/skype/63
loop15       squashf                                              /snap/squirrel
loop16       squashf                                              /snap/gnome-3-
loop17       squashf                                              /snap/canonica
loop18       squashf                                              /snap/wine-pla
loop19       squashf                                              /snap/skype/66
loop20       squashf                                              /snap/wine-pla
loop21       squashf                                              /snap/quadrapa
loop22       squashf                                              /snap/gnome-sy
loop23       squashf                                              /snap/gnome-sy
loop24       squashf                                              /snap/gnome-ch
loop25       squashf                                              /snap/ohmygira
loop26       squashf                                              /snap/gnome-ca
loop27       squashf                                              /snap/canonica
loop28       squashf                                              /snap/teatime/
loop29       squashf                                              /snap/gnome-ch
loop30       squashf                                              /snap/gnome-lo
loop31       squashf                                              /snap/gimp/83
loop32       squashf                                              /snap/core/589
loop33       squashf                                              /snap/marsshoo
loop34       squashf                                              /snap/gtk-comm
loop35       squashf                                              /snap/gimp/94
loop36       squashf                                              /snap/teatime/
loop37       squashf                                              /snap/core/613
loop38       squashf                                              /snap/gnome-cl
loop39       squashf                                              /snap/squirrel
loop40       squashf                                              /snap/gtk-comm
loop41       squashf                                              /snap/gnome-cl
mmcblk0

├─mmcblk0p1  vfat          DB20-54E6                              /boot/efi
├─mmcblk0p2  ext4          79300f87-0c38-49bb-8070-18460b8905a4   /boot
└─mmcblk0p3  crypto_       edf15eb1-9421-47de-8323-0a8c32b6cfb1

  └─mmcblk0p3_crypt
             LVM2_me       w1g34A-NYp6-GtFo-b1Kb-zeJW-WowF-o04IsU 
    ├─ubuntu--vg-root
    │        ext4          b4075b43-cf2b-40c7-bb88-0d15293378b6   /
    └─ubuntu--vg-swap_1
             swap          d0da0a8c-c645-4f46-9432-793c1a20799f   [SWAP]
mmcblk0boot0

mmcblk0boot1`

Comment: Did you change the swapfile's name? What does `grep swap /etc/fstab` show?

Comment: Btw: It is perfectly OK and preferred to ask a new question here (and not as a comment to the other question) because it is … a new question. :-)

Comment: Thanks, I took the line out about the new question!  I followed the steps in the linked thread, so I should have replaced the swapfile, and I think its name is `\swapfile`.  The result of `grep swap /etc/fstab` is this: `/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-swap_1 none            swap    sw              0       0`.  System Monitor shows me booting with 1 Gb of swap.

Comment: Maybe you don't enough space to increase the size!

Comment: @GeorgeUdosen - I have plenty of free space, using 70 out of 120 Gb on the HD.  Also, I successfully increased the swap -- it just didn't stay increased on reboot.

Comment: Ok I see this is a logical volume you can't just resize without doing same in the logical volumes it won't fly. That method you linked to is for normal partition files which this isn't!

Comment: Please do `lsblk -f` and add to your question!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `/etc/fstab` contains the line

```
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-swap_1 none swap sw 0 0
```

This means you have a swap *partition* on a logical volume group. With the command from that
[other post](https://askubuntu.com/a/1075516/879604) you created a swap *file*. Increasing the size of a swap partition is more
complicated (and I don't have enough experience with LVGs to tell you exactly how that would be done).

With Ubunutu 17 (I guess) they switched from swap partitions to swapfiles which are
easier to handle. Both is still supported and valid, they just decided that on a freshly installed
system a swapfile instead of a partition is created.

You already created the swapfile, now you only need to add it to
the `/etc/fstab`. Open the file in an editor (`sudo vim /etc/fstab`) and add the
following line (assuming your swapfile is called `/swapfile`):

```
/swapfile none swap sw 0 0
```

Now run

```
sudo swapon -a
```

This will mount the swapfile in addition to the already mounted swap partition. That is:
you will now have *both* a swap partition and a swapfile. You can leave that as it is
(and have both) or remove the line referring to the partition 
(`/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-swap_1 …`) and later remove that whole swap partition.

Whatever you do, the crucial point is to add the location of your swap space(s) to the
`/etc/fstab` so it gets mounted while booting.

I do not know whether it is a good idea to have two or more swap spaces (one partition and
one file) and whether there are drawbacks, but it is possible.

Comment: Thank you, this was critically helpful.  I decided to reinstall instead.  The result was I didn't have the interfering swap partition.  Then the swap file responded to the standard terminal commands and held the configuration on reboot.  My system performance is good!

Comment: @JustinSharber You are welcome. Nice to hear I could help you.