# Trying to increase Swap file in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: swap

I have been following the solution given in the answer here:
[How do I increase swapfile in Ubuntu 18.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1075505/how-do-i-increase-swapfile-in-ubuntu-18-04)
However when I reboot the old swap is still in place.

```
$ free -h
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available    
Mem:            31G        1.9G         27G        1.3G        2.3G         27G    
Swap:          979M          0B        979M
```

I have a recommendation from VMWare Workstation to increase it to 4 GB.

```
$ cat /etc/fstab
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot was on /dev/nvme0n1p2 during installation
UUID=daf8150f-9039-42e9-972b-873a1cc274d0 /boot           ext4    defaults        0       2
# /boot/efi was on /dev/nvme0n1p1 during installation
UUID=5181-A887  /boot/efi       vfat    umask=0077      0       1
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-swap_1 none            swap    sw              0       0
```

How do I do this?

Comment: Your using a LVM (Logiocal Volume Management) so you can't just increase the size like that! LVM hasn't been told the swap size has increased!

Comment: @GeorgeUdosen - Understood - so what's the solution?

Comment: Does a swapfile work in this case? c.f. this [answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1075505/how-do-i-increase-swapfile-in-ubuntu-18-04?noredirect=1&lq=1)