# Increased swap file size and now it doesn't get used

Tags: swap

I increased my swap file size using instructions in this [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1075505/how-do-i-increase-swapfile-in-ubuntu-18-04) and now it has stopped being used. I actually tried it a few times and it has happened every time. When I ran `swapon -s` after each attempt, the swap file's priority always showed -2 so I increased it to 100 but that didn't help either.

[image: swapon -s and free -m output screenshot]

How can I fix this? I have 16GB ram and increased the swap file size to 32GB.

Comment: You have a lot of unused RAM, so why should swap be used?

Comment: @mook765 Even when I run heavy duty apps like android studio along with emulators which eat up all the RAM, it still doesn't get used.

Comment: The system will avoid swapping because swapping reduces overall performance and responsiveness. You can play around with `swappiness`, take a look at https://askubuntu.com/questions/103915/how-do-i-configure-swappiness .

Comment: With 16G RAM, 32G swap is nuts. 4G would be more appropriate. And assuming that you don't mess with priority or vm.swappiness, you really don't want to swap unless your system usage requires/needs it. So REDUCE your swap and quit messing with it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How much swap should I take for 1GB to 8TB of RAM on 14.04 or higher?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/594054/how-much-swap-should-i-take-for-1gb-to-8tb-of-ram-on-14-04-or-higher) especially the bit at the end that allows you to see how swap is used.

Answer (score 0):

Swap size recommended settings from Ubuntu Official documentation
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SwapFaq

```
RAM   No hibernation    With Hibernation  Maximum
16GB  4GB               20GB              32GB
```

You need **4**Gb or **20**Gb of swap space. Not more.

The **priority** makes sense when there is more than one swap area.
Not used in your (1 swap area) case
You can tune the swapping behavior with **swappiness**
The same Documentation FAQ tells about **swappiness**,
see: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SwapFaq#What_is_swappiness_and_how_do_I_change_it.3F

---

Rebuild your swap setup:

```
## Delete old swapfile
sudo swapoff -a
sudo sudo rm /swapfile

## Create new swapfile (choose one according to hibernation use)
# sudo fallocate -l 20g /swapfile  ## If hibernation have to be used
sudo fallocate -l 4g /swapfile     ## If no hibernation use is planed
sudo chmod 600 /swapfile
sudo mkswap /swapfile

## Enable new swapfile
sudo swapon /swapfile

## /etc/fstab check
# since /swapfile was used, a line should be present in /etc/fstab file
# search for and check '/swapfile swap swap defaults 0 0'

## Show swap settings and usage
swapon -s
free -h
```

Comment: That bit of the Ubuntu SwapFaq actually originates [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/594054/how-much-swap-should-i-take-for-1gb-to-8tb-of-ram-on-14-04-or-higher/594402#594402)  **>:-)**