# How to increase swap partition when installing Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: partitioning, 20.04, swap

Is there a way to do the default installation but have a larger swap partition? Thanks.

Comment: What's wrong with the "something else" partitioning option?

Comment: I'd like to keep the default on everything, except partitioning. The "something else" expects me to define everything.

Comment: "Something else" is ONLY partitioning.

Comment: Why would you need to do that? The system will increase it when needed.

Comment: @Rinzwind re: *"The system will increase it when needed"*... huh? If I understand what you're saying... how do you come to that conclusion?

Answer (score 1):

The default installation is what it is: the default installation. It assumes defaults for everything, including the size of your swap. It is important to note that the default install does not anymore create a swap partition. Swap is now implemented as a file.

It is [quite easy to change the size of a swap file](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1075505/how-do-i-increase-swapfile-in-ubuntu-18-04/1075516#1075516), which is what a default install implements, after install. So go for a default install and then change swap if that is the only aspect you want to customize.

For control, there is the "Something else" option. There you are in control about everything, including the configuration of swap.