# Swap file hard disk it appears to have holes

Tags: partitioning, hard-drive, swap, dd

guys i need to enable swap on my ubuntu system and i want to avoid swap on SSD or format my hard disk that doesn't contain the swap partition.
So i was trying to create a file swap and use it but, following the ubuntu guide:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SwapFaq
i'm not able to figure out the problem.
First of all i can't allocate the file with fallocate because it says operation not permitted, then i create a file with dd with all zeros but after setting the right permission and after calling mkswap, the command swapon fails saying: kipping - it appears to have holes.
I want to use file swap to avoid create partition on a disk with already a whole partition, and i want it on the hard disk not on the SSD.
Can you help me please?
[those are the steps that i did](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1lbCA.png)

The problem is that swapon got interrupted because the file appears to have holes.
It is created using dd.

To resume what is the problem: my system has no swap at all. I want to add a new one on secondary hard disk, instead of primary SSD, but i want to avoid format it and create the partition. That is why i create the swap file. But when i try to active it with the command "swapon" i receive the error: it appears to have holes.

Comment: Hi and welcome. What version of Ubuntu? Why do you want a swap file and why not on the SSD where it would be much faster?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I increase swapfile in Ubuntu 18.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1075505/how-do-i-increase-swapfile-in-ubuntu-18-04)

Comment: Hi David, i'm using ubuntu 18.04. I want swap on hard disk because SSD will be saturated quite soon if i swap upon it because a huge amount of write op can decrease its life.

Comment: Hi vanadium i already follow that instruction but i receive the holes error. I'm using dd command to create the swap file.

Comment: You must `sudo fallocate ...`. This will grab all the disk blocks in one contiguous block. Creating the file with `dd` allocates disk blocks a few at a time, with no guarantee of contiguous groups of blocks, thus, the complaint about "holes".

Comment: Hi, this is different of what the tutorial says but i tried fallocate, but it says operation not permitted

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! I believe that this is the answer you require. https://askubuntu.com/a/796997/225694 you'll note that sudo is required for all the commands in the answer that create and implement the swap.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I add swap after system installation?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/33697/how-do-i-add-swap-after-system-installation)

Comment: No that question regard the partition swap, i want to enable a file to swap

Answer (score 1):

### To Enable Hibernation in 20.04 Using a Swapfile:

I used this method yesterday to increase my **swapfile** size and enable hibernation, (optional). Last paragraph is how I search for holes.

**Increase `swapfile` size to match RAM size up to 8GB.**

- Check the swap that is in use:

  ```
  sudo swapon -s
  ```
- If swap partition(s) are found:

  ```
  sudo swapoff -a
  sudo nano -Bw /etc/fstab
  ```
- Add `#` before the `UUID` of the swap partition(s):

  ```
  # UUID=XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX   none   swap    sw     0       0
  ```
- Add a line for the `swapfile`, if one does not exist:

  ```
  swapfile   none    swap     sw      0       0
  ```
- Create the `swapfile`:

  ```
  sudo fallocate -l XG /swapfile*
  ```

  where `X` is `swapfile`'s size in GB:

  ```
  sudo mkswap /swapfile
  sudo chmod 0600 /swapfile
  sudo swapon /swapfile
  ```
- Reboot:

  ```
  sudo reboot
  ```

**Add `resume` location and offset to `grub.cfg`:**

- Edit `/etc/default/grub`:

  ```
  GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash resume=UUID=XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX resume_offset=XXXXX"
  ```
- Use `UUID` from root.
- Use offset from:

  ```
  sudo filefrag -v /swapfile |grep " 0:"| awk '{print $4}'
  ```
- Update GRUB:

  ```
  sudo update-grub
  ```
- Test hibernation:

  ```
  sudo systemctl hibernate
  ```

A hibernate button can be added using GNOME extensions.

Note that there is a slight possibility of getting holes in a `swapfile` when creating it with `fallocate`. `/var/log/syslog` can be searched for the phrase `swapon: swapfile has holes` to ensure there will be no data loss.

Comment: Thanks but those are just the step that i did. i just want to figure out the error.

Comment: Did I read that your system has a swap partition and a swapfile?

Comment: No my system has no swap at all. I want to add a new one on secondary hard disk,  but i want to avoid format it and create partition. That is why i create the swap file. But when i try to active it with the command swapon i receive the error: it appears to have holes.

Comment: Are you creating it on the SSD and then moving it? I missed why you are not just adding a swap partition to the HDD? That would be easy.

Comment: I already tried to create first on SSD and then move it on HDD but the same error happen. I know that is easy but doesn't figure out the holes problem.