# How Do I Decrease the Size of a Preexisting Swap File Without Removing it?

Tags: swap

After seeing this post: [How do I increase swapfile in Ubuntu 18.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1075505/how-do-i-increase-swapfile-in-ubuntu-18-04), I was wondering, how do I decrease the size of the swap file without removing it?

Comment: Why the need to decrease the size of a swapfile without removing it? What exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Decreasing a swapfile would be done the same way as creating one, as they’re fixed in size to begin with. The only difference is that you would specify a smaller size than currently exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how do I decrease the size of the swap file without removing it?

This question is rather irrelevant. Swap space must be taken out of use before changing it. The command `sudo fallocate -l 4G /swapfile` (with an adjusted size) will overwrite your existing swapfile if you do not delete it first.