# why ubuntu takes too long to startup after removing swap partition?

Tags: boot, partitioning, gparted, startup, swap

yesterday i decided to remove SWAP partition of my ubuntu 21.10 (which is dual booted with windows 11).

using GParted i removed swap partition.
now, ubuntu takes too long to boot.
it is installed on a ssd and before this operation it used to start in just some seconds but now it takes near one minutes to startup.

how can i find the reason and solve that?

Comment: Did you remove swap from `/etc/fstab`? Does `systemd-analyze blame` inform? Look at the boot log with `sudo journalctl  -b 0`. Read `man fstab systemd-analyze journalctl`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your system may desperately be looking for the swap partition. Edit `/etc/fstab` and remove (or comment out, i.e., place a `#` in front of) the line that does announce your swap partition.

Deleting swap space may not have been the smartest move. You may want to [create a swapfile](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1075505/how-do-i-increase-swapfile-in-ubuntu-18-04/1075516#1075516) instead. Currently, default Ubuntu installations set up a swap file instead of a dedicated swap partition.

Comment: this solved the problem. thx.