# What is using such a large portion of my memory?

Tags: 16.04, server, memory-usage

I am setting up a home server for plex, storage, and a few VMs. I have everything loaded and running and was checking to what ram I had left to start a few VMs and noticed I was using more than half of my ram and hadn't even started a VM yet. I ran "sudo htop" to see if I could find out what was using it, but it doesn't show much. Haven't been using Linux long, but I thought it was very lite on resources. Is there another application I can use to find out what is using the ram?

```
    bob@ducktape:~$ uname -a
    Linux ducktape 4.4.0-112-generic #135-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jan 19 11:48:36 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

    bob@ducktape:~$ free -m
                  total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
    Mem:          48291       26613       18648          28        3029       20595
    Swap:             0           0           0

    bob@ducktape:~$ ps aux --sort -rss | head -n 5
    USER       PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND
    plex     19720  9.3  1.2 1177412 597384 ?      Sl   00:11  71:45 /usr/lib/plexmediaserver/Plex Media Server
    plex     19789  0.0  0.1 344168 92808 ?        Sl   00:11   0:28 /usr/lib/plexmediaserver/Plex DLNA Server
    plex     19748  0.1  0.1 1857400 66116 ?       SNl  00:11   0:46 Plex Plug-in [com.plexapp.system] /usr/lib/plexmediaserver/Resources/Plug-ins-f54242b6b/Framework.bundle/Contents/Resources/Versions/2/Python/bootstrap.py --server-version 1.10.1.4602-f54242b6b /usr/lib/plexmediaserver/Resources/Plug-ins-f54242b6b/System.bundle
    plex     19822  0.0  0.0 955492 47048 ?        Sl   00:11   0:12 Plex Plug-in [com.plexapp.plugins.WebTools] /usr/lib/plexmediaserver/Resources/Plug-ins-f54242b6b/Framework.bundle/Contents/Resources/Versions/2/Python/bootstrap.py --server-version 1.10.1.4602-f54242b6b /var/lib/plexmediaserver/Library/Application Support/Plex Media Server/Plug-ins/WebTools.bundle

bob@ducktape:~$ free --si -h
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:            49G         27G         19G         29M        3.1G         21G
Swap:            0B          0B          0B
```

[htop output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XxJo5.jpg)

Comment: Please include the output of `free -m`

Comment: How can I copy from putty and get it to maintain formatting?

Comment: Copy/paste your formatted text, mark it and click on '{}'. Works only in questions and answers, not in comment.

Comment: 20GB memory used is unreasonable, unless you have a few VM's or other heavy services. What does `ps aux --sort -rss | head -n 5` show?

Comment: So plex is the memory hog. I don't know how plex uses memory, but googling indicates that you're not the only one...

Comment: Why does htop show only 1.2%? Is that not an accurate picture of my system?

Comment: You have multiple plex processes. Also you have a snap that consumes a bit.

Comment: How do I mark this as answered? and thanks for the information. I will research the ps command. And sorry I can't seem to figure out the command formatting.

Comment: @Dartrunner Either wait for someone to post an answer or post an answer on your own. [That's perfectly ok.](https://askubuntu.com/help/self-answer) Then mark the given answer (which may be yours) as accepted by clicking the gray hook until it turns green.

Comment: 1.2% isn't that much of memory being used.  Of 48GB 1.2% is only 0.576GB.  Try looking at `free --si -h` as a command or something like that.  It might be caching that is using up so much and that will be released when needed.

Comment: This answer here:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/20277787/2012250  allows you to actually see the amount of RAM being used by a specific application.

Comment: This could work if some would show us how to apply to Pex....https://askubuntu.com/questions/120765/memory-limiting-solutions-for-greedy-applications-that-can-crash-os

Comment: I think I figured it out after much googling and reading the comments. I am using ZFS and its mem usage is not reported anywhere. Thanks for the help, and the comments led me in the direction I needed.