# Process gets killed with Out of Memory - How to limit memory for the process?

Tags: java, ram, process, matlab, syslog

I have installed Matlab 2020a in Ubuntu 20.04. When trying to run a code the Matlab program is getting killed, but it runs in another system perfectly fine. Checking resources while running shows that 8gb RAM and 10gb Swap are getting exhausted before getting killed.

Tried changing Java heap memory to around 1.5GB, as well as unchecking the maximum array limit option from workspace settings in Matlab preferences.

`dmseg` output has these lines

```
oom-kill:constraint=CONSTRAINT_NONE,nodemask=(null),cpuset=/,mems_allowed=0,global_oom,task_memcg=/user.slice/user-1000.slice/user@1000.service,task=MATLAB,pid=14659,uid=1000
[ 2166.872604] Out of memory: Killed process 14659 (MATLAB) total-vm:24372208kB, anon-rss:7121400kB, file-rss:0kB, shmem-rss:4kB, UID:1000 pgtables:35440kB oom_score_adj:0
```

`syslog` has these lines

```
kernel: [16207.494793] Out of memory: Killed process 50687 (MATLAB) total-vm:22123872kB, anon-rss:6511936kB, file-rss:0kB, shmem-rss:92kB, UID:1000 pgtables:31144kB oom_score_adj:0
/usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1638]: (EE) client bug: timer event9 tap: scheduled expiry is in the past (-998ms), your system is too slow
kernel: [16208.142159] oom_reaper: reaped process 50687 (MATLAB), now anon-rss:0kB, file-rss:0kB, shmem-rss:108kB
```

Is there a way I can limit the memory and swap used by `matlab`? Have tried `ulimit` with `-m` and `-v` flags, but then `matlab` won't open at all.

This issue is not there in windows in the same machine, so the issue seems only for MATLAB in Ubuntu. Is there a way to make it work in ubuntu?

Comment: What process gets  killed? If Java heap is limited to 1.5 GB it shouldn't use too much more than that. Take a look at `top`or `htop` to see who is eating up memory. Also look at log files, JAVAs and ubuntus in /var/log ... especially syslog and dmesg.

Comment: `matlab` gets killed, and `dmesg` notifies of the `out of memory` issue for matlab.

Comment: used `htop` and it shows `matlab` eating up memory while running the code.

Comment: Try asking in a  MathLab forum .. they might know how to limit memory usage. It sound much like a MathLab configuration issue.

Comment: The  MATLAB forum doesn't seem to be active with my question.

Answer (score 0):

`ulimit` is your friend. Check out the -m flag. I think you set this before you launch your process and it applies from then on (in the current shell).

FROM POST [Memory limiting solutions for greedy applications that can crash OS?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/120765/memory-limiting-solutions-for-greedy-applications-that-can-crash-os)